# Using Java and regex, how can I capture an uncertain(?) group?

Tags: java, regex

Let's suppose I have this regex:

```
Hello\smy\sname\sis((PETER)|(HARRY)|(EMMA))(and\smy\sage\sis(\d+))?
```

Capturing the names is pretty simple, I would just write something like this:

```
if(matcher.group(1).equals(matcher.group(2)) {
  String str = matcher.group(2);
}
```

...

However for the age:

```
if(!matcher.group(5).isEmpty()) {
  int age = matcher.group(6);
}
```

This only works if the text the pattern is working on actually has the age part, if it doesnt, an error pops. So how can I capture the uncertain group?

Comment: I don't think there is a way other than surrounding it with the try-catch... and then catch that specific exception. If the exception gets thrown then do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an optional group doesn't exist in your input string, the `group` method returns `null`. Therefore an `NullPointerException` is probably thrown in your `if` statement. Instead check if `matcher.group(5)` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is a bit strange. I assume you only want to capture the name and the age. There is no reason to put parentheses around each individual name, or to make the optional second part a capturing group (unless you have some need to see that whole part of the sentence, and not just the age itself; but the age is the only part that can vary, the rest being a constant string).

Also, it isn't possible with this regex to put a space before or after the name, which is odd. I would think you would want a regex like this instead:

```regex
Hello\smy\sname\sis\s(PETER|HARRY|EMMA)(?:\sand\smy\sage\sis\s(\d+))?
```

Notice that the second have has been made a non-capturing group by putting `?:` after the opening parenthesis. The name will now be group 1, and group 2 will be `null` if the second half was not provided, otherwise it will contain the digits of the age.

For example, `"Hello my name is EMMA and my age is 21"` will yield:

- Group 1: `EMMA`
- Group 2: `21`

Don't forget to double the backslashes when putting the regex into a string in your Java source code.

Comment: I know it is strange, this isn't my code, I just wrote this one to explain my question. Thanks for replying anyway, I did not know about the non-capturing group by using ?: , it might be useful :)